# Resharper custom pattern for removing blank lines C#

Tags: c#, regex, resharper

A colleague encountered a problem where he had **singular blank lines** after **method heads** and after **if conditions**. Our custom **Resharper** template does not seem to fix this. I know there are options to remove these blank lines, but those options also remove blank lines between fields and such. For example, a blank line between two sets of private fields could indicate different categories of fields, whatever the criteria may be. 
So what I want to achieve is this:

```
public void Do()

{
  if (true)

   {
     //something
   }
}
```

becomes

```
public void Do()
{
  if (true)
   {
    //something
   }
```

Can this be achieved with a custom pattern via **regex** detecting that blank line? I've never created custom Resharper patterns, and I'm still in my apprenticeship, if that matters.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it worth trying to replace `^\s*$` with nothing and `\n+` with `\n`

Comment: But then a code cleanup would remove all blank lines wouldn't it?

Comment: see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

After a deeper look into this it seems that what you are trying to do is not possible with Resharper patterns. This is what a Jetbrains guy writes:

"Search with Pattern is designed to work with pure code tree ignoring all whitespace, comments, etc."   [source](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206654545-cleanup-using-custom-pattern)

But this is still a good sample for you on a pattern creation.

1 . Go to Resharper => options => code inspection => custom pattern => add pattern

2 . This is how your pattern should look like:

[image]

4. Please pay attention to the right pane - you have to add  "statement placeholder" named $statement$ and an "identifier placeholder" called $methodName$.
5. Change the pattern severity from "Do not show" to "suggestion" or "warning" or else you want see it.

Comment: Would this cover methods of any accessibility and return types? I followed each step, but now Resharper marks all my test methods as wrong, even those without blank lines, and applying the pattern changes nothing.